# Flutter web | failed to create Docker file

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Below issue facing while creating docker file in flutter web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IeND.png)

anyone have idea about how to create docker file in flutter web.....

I tried many resources but still stuck in issue...

resource or link or solution about same

Comment: Do you want to run a flutter web app inside a docker container? Or what exactly do you mean bei creating a docker file in flutter web?

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad Yes I want to run flutter web app inside a docker container but i faced the above issue

Comment: Does my Dockerfile help you?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help you without seeing your Dockerfile.
This is the multistaged one I use with nginx:

```
#Stage 1 - Install dependencies and build the app
FROM debian:latest AS build-env

# Install flutter dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl git wget unzip libgconf-2-4 gdb libstdc++6 libglu1-mesa fonts-droid-fallback lib32stdc++6 python3
RUN apt-get clean

# Clone the flutter repo
RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git /usr/local/flutter

# Set flutter path
# RUN /usr/local/flutter/bin/flutter doctor -v
ENV PATH="/usr/local/flutter/bin:/usr/local/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:${PATH}"

# Run flutter doctor
RUN flutter doctor -v
# Enable flutter web
RUN flutter channel master
RUN flutter upgrade
RUN flutter config --enable-web

# Copy files to container and build
RUN mkdir /app/
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN flutter create .
RUN flutter build web

# Stage 2 - Create the run-time image
FROM nginx:1.21.1-alpine
COPY --from=build-env /app/build/web /usr/share/nginx/html
```

If you need a highly optimized image I would not use this one. How ever it does the trick for me.